# How to have Ant/build.xml print a setting?

Tags: android, xml, ant

I'm working with Ant from the command line with Android. `<sdk>/tools/ant//build.xml` has lines like the following:

```
<!-- clean target -->
<target name="clean" depends="-setup, -pre-clean"
        description="Removes output files created by other targets.">
    <delete dir="${out.absolute.dir}" verbose="${verbose}" />
    <delete dir="${gen.absolute.dir}" verbose="${verbose}" />
...
```

I searched through the XML file, but I only found three usage of the word print (`printseeds`, `printusage` and `printmapping`). So print does not appear to be the way to print values.

How do I add a statement to print `out.absolute.dir` and `gen.absolute.dir`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use the `echo` task to print the values of the properties as follows:

```
<echo message="out.absolute.dir: ${out.absolute.dir}" />
<echo message="gen.absolute.dir: ${gen.absolute.dir}" />
```